# Spring framework and tomcat - How to enable following symbolic links to folders?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat6, symlink

I have a web-application written in Java + spring framework. The app-server used is tomcat. Suppose the web-application name is "sample-webapp". If I create a symbolic link under sample-webapp/resources/ like this-

> ls -l
>
> .../sample-webapp/resources/temp-csv-location -> /tmp/csv-location

Here "temp-csv-location" is a symbolic link.

Now if I refer to a file inside this directory in a jsp page, something like

```
<a href="http://localhost:8080/sample-webapp/resources/temp-csv-location/test.csv">Click</a>
```

It gives me a 404 error. I confirmed that the test.csv file is present in /tmp/csv-location/. I confirmed the permissions as well. In plain tomcat usage, we could add "allowLinking=true" in context.xml.

Is there a way to do this in the spring framework?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative and generic solution for your problem is writing a Servlet that handle all requests that math your start path, then the Servlet will handle the providing of file by resolving its path.

For setting up the Servlet, you have to put this in your web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>csvFileDownloadServlet</filter-name>
    <filter-class>edu.sharif.resource.CSVFileDownloadServlet</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>csvFileDownloadServlet</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/resources/temp-csv-location/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Then you should write the edu.sharif.resource.CSVFileDownloadServlet class. You can find several implementation for this problem via a simple search, for example:

- [Returning CSV file from Servlet using ServletOutputStream over HTTPS in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899858/returning-csv-file-from-servlet-using-servletoutputstream-over-https-in-internet)
- http://www.coderanch.com/t/366358/Servlets/java/File-download-servlet
- http://www.dzone.com/snippets/example-file-download-servlet