# In java web setups, how to implement TXT/CSV downloads?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

for example, I am already at the backend and I have data (List of SomeObject) and I want it to be downloaded (instead of redirecting to a page). I am not really sure how to implement it.

QUESTION:

1. Am I supposed to create an actual CSV file first (in the server) and let the user download it, (delete after download) or is there a way to let the user download it without making any physical file?
2. Anyone familiar with cubby? or Java web Actions / ActionResults? I can't seem to get the Request/Response objects in the server actions :/ Thanks.

Comment: Are the two questsion related? It's not clear if you want to implement a CSV download in cubby/java web actions. If not you should separate them into different questions

Comment: They are, but separate answers will be enough :)

Comment: Maybe code snippet from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/899858/returning-csv-file-from-servlet-using-servletoutputstream-over-https-in-internet can help you?